# Почему представление не видит, что находится в переменной?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть, например, 100 блоков `div` на сайте. Каждый `div` - это место в кинотеатре. При нажатии на один из блоков его уникальный `id` записывается в переменную `$arr`. Таким образом я реализую функционал заказа и выбора сразу нескольких мест для бронирования.

```
$arr = [];
$link = $(location).attr('href').slice(36);
$('.btn-warning').each(function() {
  $place_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $arr.push($place_id);
  });

 $.ajax({
   url: "/film_sessions/" + $link,
   type: "get",
   data: { data_value: JSON.stringify($arr) }
 });
```

Дальше я получаю этот массив с помощью AJAX запроса и отправляю в контроллер Rails:

```
before_action :get_booking_place_array, only: [:show]

def get_booking_place_array
  @test_test = params[:data_value]
  puts "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
  puts @test_test
  puts "----------------------------------------------------------------------"
end

def show
  ...
  @test_test = []
end
```

Вывод полученных данных планируется в модальном окне:

```
<div id="data2">
  <% @test_test.each do %>
    <h1>hello</h1>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что если в экшене `show` не объявить переменную `@test_test` и не присвоить ей пустой массив, то при заходе на страницу `show` будет ошибка:

> undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Иначе - она постоянно будет равна пустому массиву. То есть если я выбираю несколько мест (`dіv`) и захожу в терминал, то вижу там такие записи:

> ["place_5","place_6","place_32"]

Я понимаю, что запись выводится благодаря строчке `puts @test_test` в методе `get_booking_place_array`.

Однако, с помощью гема `web-console` я могу проверить, что переменная `@test_test` на самой странице равняется пустому массиву (`[]`).

Выходит, что в терминале в переменной данные есть, но в представлении они не распознаются, и я использую две разные переменные. Как это исправить?

Comment: `{ data_value: JSON.stringify($arr) }` <- Зачем передавать параметры в JSON, внутри которых есть JSON-строка, в которой записаны данные в JSON? .-.

Comment: @D-side Этот код взял из примера, но проблема не в этом в любом случае)

Comment: А вот это мы вот-вот выясним... :)

Comment: > *Проблема в том, что если в экшене show не объявить переменную @test_test и не присвоить ей пустой массив, то при заходе на страницу show будет ошибка*:

**Неверю (с)!**